# Canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a question about HTML Canvas i'm having trouble making it work it was working fine back in May, what could have caused Canvas not to work anymore? Does a new Canvas version exist this was working fine in May and i tried it in september and it stopped working

```
$('#download').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#firstshirt'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
      a.download = 'test.jpg';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});


var download = document.getElementById("download"),
result = document.getElementById("previewImage");

function renderContent() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("firstshirt"), {
    allowTaint: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    result.appendChild(canvas);
    download.style.display = "inline";
    download.href = result.children[0].toDataURL();
  });
}

function downloadImage() {

}

if (document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image") != undefined) {
  document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image").onclick = renderContent;
  download.onclick = downloadImage
}
```

Comment: Could you just give a bit more information. What are you trying to achieve? Are you getting any error? What behavior were you expecting vs what's happening?

Comment: i was expecting for an image to preview and im not getting any errors and no image is being previewed here is the site if you want to give it a try on the  left hand side there is a preview button https://torcdesign.com/prison45/

Comment: when i hit F12 i get this error                                                        
     Uncaught TypeError: html2canvas(...).then is not a function
    at renderContent ((index):2670)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> ((index):2514)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [this html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) and you are using [latest release](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/v0.4/readme.md) (0.4.1).

The latest release version does not return a promise and uses `onrendered` while the [latest dev version](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) returns a promise (maybe still has the onrendered option but it's not documented).

So you should stick with onrendered and keep the latest release version or use latest dev with promises. If you want to support browsers that don't have native promises you need a [polyfil](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise).